# Undefined function 'create' for writing XLSX from Matlab

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to create an Excel file from Matlab and write in that file some result from running a Matlab script. The problem is that when I try to add the result in the Excel file I have an error about the "create" function.

I'm using POI library and I've tried to add all the libraries to Matlab but it seems nothing doesn't work.

This is a part of the code that I use in Matlab script.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

% javaaddpath([fileparts(mfilename) filesep 'jars']);
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

instream = FileInputStream(ReportFile);
book = WorkbookFactory.create(instream);
sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
toprow = sheet.getRow(0);
UnitColFound = false;
UnitColIndex = 0;
```

The Excel file is created but nothing is written in the file. The following error appears:

```
Undefined function 'create' for input arguments of type 'org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory'.

Error in AddUnitResultToReport (line 33)
book = WorkbookFactory.create(instream);
```

Do you have any idea how can I solve this problem?

Comment: `create` is a static method on `WorkbookFactory`, maybe [follow this bit of the matlab docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/javamethod.html#btq0k89-1) to call it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use XSSF or HSSF workookFactory ( depends if you want .xls or .xlsx file ) because the `create` that you are using is a static method.

So, if you want a .xlsx file use 
`Workbook workbook = XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(instream);`

If you want a .xls file use 
`Workbook workbook = HSSFWorkbookFactory.create(instream);`